# Populate input field with value from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

In my rails app, i need to populate 1 field with value that came in json, which was returned by clicking on link. Is there any tutorial on how to correctly use ajax to do such thing?
Here is my plan how to do this:

1.Send get request to my json `appname/controller/action.json`

2.`parse` this json on client side

3.set `value` of field with parsed json

Comment: You can read the documentation of: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. jQuery would take care of parsing the JSON for your but if you have to do it yourself, for whatever reason: [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript). If you have a complex data structure, this might help to figure out how to access it: [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196). How to set the value of input is also explained in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your json string is like that

```
 [{"id":"1","name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test2"},{"id":"3","name":"test3"},{"id":"4","name":"test4"},{"id":"5","name":"test5"}]
```

use the $.getJSON method:

```
$.getJSON('/appname/controller/action.json', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        $('body').append($('<div>', {
            text: element.name
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: this is almost the way i did it. Except i just assigned to value of input data because i have only one item in my json, so each is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data is the JSON object, you could use this inside the $.getJSON callback:

```
var $inputs = $('form input');
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $inputs.filter(function() {
    return key == this.name;
  }).val(value);
});
```

**second way**
eg: [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/XspdN/)